# Custom Font not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, nsstring

i am working on one Project on my Project i want to add custom font like as `Calibri Bold.ttf` and  `Calibri.ttf` for this i added this both file in my application and in my info.plist file i added `Fonts Provided by Aplication` then it is shown in my Font but when i want to set in to my String it shows me error like as

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString *)getAttributedString:(NSString*)lostr
{
NSMutableAttributedString *loMutAttStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:lostr];
NSArray *loArr = [lostr componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
NSRange loRange1 = NSMakeRange(0,[[loArr objectAtIndex:0] length]-1);
NSRange loRange2 = NSMakeRange([lostr length]-[[loArr objectAtIndex:[loArr count]-1] length]-1,[[loArr objectAtIndex:[loArr count]-1] length]+1);

UIColor *loColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIColor *loColr1= [UIColor  grayColor];

[loMutAttStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:loColor range:loRange1];
[loMutAttStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri Bold" size:30] range:loRange1];
if([loArr count] > 1)
{
    [loMutAttStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:loColr1 range:loRange2];
    [loMutAttStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:30] range:loRange2];
}
return loMutAttStr;
}
```

then it shows me error `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil value'` in line

```
[loMutAttStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri Bold" size:30] range:loRange1];
```

Please give me solution for this here my string is not nil and when i set font `HelveticaNeue` instead of `Calibri` then it is working fine.

Comment: What are the values of `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:10]` and `[UIFont fontWithName:@"CalibriBold" size:10]?

Answer (score 0):

Look here for adding custom font http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Print fonts supported by app

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked it and it was Print Custum Font name i mean `Calibri` and `CalibriBold`.

Comment: OK. Use this  `[UIFont fontWithName:@"CalibriBold" size:30]`

Comment: remove space between `Calibri` and `Bolid`

Comment: please follow this http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/